# Using Twilio Verify Service API with JSON

Tags: twilio

I am calling the Twilio Verify Rest API using JSON in the body, but it is returning an error " Your AccountSid or AuthToken was incorrect."

Here is my setup:

I used a Base64 encoder> entered my AccountSID:Auth token> and entered it into the "Value" as seen in the screenshot below.

I am not sure exactly what I am doing wrong. Any help?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Make sure to send the body of your request as `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, not JSON.

Example:

```
curl -X POST https://verify.twilio.com/v2/Services/VAXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/Verifications \
--data-urlencode "To=+15017122661" \
--data-urlencode "Channel=sms" \
-u ACXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX:your_auth_token
```

Comment: I'm sorry I don't really know what you mean, please elaborate

Comment: I have to use JSON though, not curl. Any suggestions? I am sending through Adalo, which requires JSON

Comment: Maybe you can tag Adalo and ask that community how to structure this specific type of request?